# Amplify pull --sandboxId <UUID> results in "Failed to pull sandbox app"

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I'm following [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/generate-model/q/integration/react-native/#add-the-iscomplete-boolean-field) tutorial for setting up AWS Amplify and can't seem to generate the data models from Amplify Studio with the "Amplify pull --sandboxId <UUID>" command with my ID. This results in the "Failed to pull sandbox app" error message. I have no clue what the reason for this is, if anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it.

I ran "amplify env pull" with no issues as well as just "amplify pull". No idea what could be causing this new issue, I can't find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue, it happens if you run "amplify init" before running this command.